# How do I find the roots of $x\sin^2(x) - \frac1x$ on the open interval $(0, 2\pi)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Sorry for the poor formatting, this is my first post. I was asked to find the number of critical points of a function, the derivative of which is $x\sin^2(x) - 1/x$, on the open interval $(0, 2\pi)$. Thus, I'm trying to find how many values of $x$ for which $x\sin^2(x) - 1/x = 0$ is true. I used Desmos and saw that the answer was $4$, but I want to know how to solve the problem analytically. I've tried substituting $(1-\cos^2(x))$ for $\sin^2(x)$ and manipulating the function a number of other ways but I still can't figure out how to solve it. This has been giving me a headache for over an hour; help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an highly transcendal equation and then it will not show any analytical solution. So, numerical methods are required and, as a consequence, you need to generate a good starting value for each root.

I think that is would be better to look for the zero's of
$$f(x)=x^2\sin^2(x) - 1$$

If you plot  it, you will notice a root close to $\frac \pi 3$, two roots on each side of $\pi$ and last root close to $2\pi$.

For the first root, make a Taylor expansion
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{12}-1\right)+\frac{1}{18} \left(9 \pi +\sqrt{3} \pi ^2\right)
   \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^2\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms, solve for $x$
$$x_1=\frac{\pi }{3}+\frac{36-3 \pi ^2}{18 \pi +2 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2}\approx 1.11763$$ while the exact solution is $1.11416$.

For the second and third roots
$$f(x)=-1+\pi ^2 (x-\pi )^2+O\left((x-\pi )^3\right)$$ which gives
$$x_2=\pi -\frac 1 \pi\approx 2.82328 \qquad\qquad x_3=\pi +\frac 1 \pi\approx 3.45990$$ while the exact solutions are $2.77260$ and $3.43683$.

For the last root
$$f(x)=-1+4 \pi ^2 (x-2 \pi )^2+O\left((x-2 \pi )^3\right)$$ which gives
$$x_4=2\pi-\frac 1 {2\pi} \approx 6.12403$$ while the exact solution is $6.11902$.

Using these estimates (easily derived), to polish the roots for any accuracy, Nexton method will work like a charm.

Comment: Note: The OP asks to solve for just number of roots in (0, 2pi) i.e. how to show there're 4 roots without graphing I suppose.

Comment: @GarethMa. You are right ! I did misread. I shall delete my answer in a few seconds. Cheers :-(

Comment: I don't think deleting is necessary, it's still helpful :)

Comment: The highest level of calculus I know right know is applications of derivatives and basic integrals so I don't understand most of this answer yet, but thanks for the response! It made me curious about Taylor expansion and now that I've looked into it, I think I can get a basic grasp of it. Thanks!